# Stretch an element to the end of the automatically calculated grid, not just the explicit grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

In a CSS grid, you can use `grid-column: 1 / -1` to stretch an element across the entire *explicit* grid. However, if you add new elements and the grid automatically has more columns than explicitly stated, this doesn't have the same effect.

Is there any value I can put instead of `-1` that will force the item to stretch all the way to the end of the grid?

In the following example, because `grid-auto-flow` is set to `column`, the extra elements add new columns. I want the `.stretch` element to stretch the entire width of the grid, not just the width of the specified 3x3 grid.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  width: 300px;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 15px;
}

.stretch {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="stretch item">
    Stretched
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

One *hacky* idea is to make the element span a large number of columns:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  width: 300px;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 15px;
}

.stretch {
  grid-column: span 20;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="stretch item">
    Stretched
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="stretch item">
    Stretched
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
</div>
```

Pay attention as this hack works only if you don't specify `grid-column-gap` and you keep the implicit new column to have `auto` width.

Adding gaps will break it:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap:1px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  width: 300px;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 15px;
}

.stretch {
  grid-column: span 20;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="stretch item">
    Stretched
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="stretch item">
    Stretched
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
</div>
```

Making the implicit column different from `auto` will break it:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-columns:10px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  width: 300px;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 15px;
}

.stretch {
  grid-column: span 20;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="stretch item">
    Stretched
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="stretch item">
    Stretched
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If you want to consider gaps simply consider margin and in case you want to define width define it on the elements.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left:-10px;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-left:10px;
}

.stretch {
  grid-column: span 20;
}

.item:nth-child(n + 8) {
  border-color:blue;
  min-width:40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="stretch item">
    Stretched
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="stretch item">
    Stretched
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    .
  </div>
</div>
```