Remove Child From CSS Grid
I have a form that is set up as a css grid, but I would like the submit button to always be at the bottom-right of the form.
I have seen some examples of how to force a child onto a new row, and I'm currently using that code, but it always puts the button at the bottom-left.
I've also toyed around with grid-column-end: -1, and that works for some widths, but it creates extra grids as the screen gets wider.


body {
  background: silver;
}

#sowing form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(175px, 1fr));
  gap: 1rem;
}

#sowing fieldset {
  border: 1px solid white;
}

#sowing legend {
  margin-left: 0.25rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

#sowing label, #sowing input {
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% - 0.5rem);
}

#sowing label {
  margin-bottom: 0.25rem;
}

#sowing input {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

#sowing input[type="submit"] {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  place-self: end;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
}
<main id="sowing">
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Personal Information</legend>
    <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="firstname">
    <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lastname">
    <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
    <input type="text" id="phone">
    <label for="email">E-Mail Address</label>
    <input type="text" id="email">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Mailing Address</legend>
    <label for="address">Street</label>
    <input type="text" id="address">
    <label for="city">City</label>
    <input type="text" id="city">
    <label for="state">State</label>
    <input type="text" id="state">
    <label for="zip">Zip Code</label>
    <input type="text" id="zip">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Credit Card Information</legend>
    <label for="ccnumber">Credit Card Number</label>
    <input type="text" id="ccnumber">
    <label for="expiration">Expiration Date</label>
    <input type="text" id="expiration">
    <label for="code">CVV</label>
    <input type="text" id="code">
  </fieldset>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</main>



The form is display: grid, each fieldset is at least 175px and at most 100%, and it puts them beside each other as many times as the window width allows.  I would just like the Submit button to be attached to the bottom-right, regardless of the number of columns.

#sowing form -- is this a typo? It does not match the HTML?

If grid-column-end: -1 works for some widths then a simple media query will make it work for other widths. Perhaps you are overthinking this?

Unfortunately, there is no way to target the last column in an implicit grid - See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56932412/how-to-span-to-the-last-column-in-an-implicit-grid

I have fixed the typos in your snippet ... it now properly demonstrates your form and the issue you are asking about.

Oh, sorry about the #sowing bit.  It's actually on <main> that I didn't paste.  The CSS is correct.

Your question asks "remove child from CSS grid?" ... and that’s exactly the right approach. Your questions answers itself.
The solution is to exclude the submit button from the grid. Rather than styling the entire form as a grid, create a wrapper element to contain your fieldsets and style just that portion of the form as a grid. Then just use text-align: right on the form to get the submit button (styled as display: inline) to sit on the right-hand side.


body {
  background: silver;
}

#sowing {
  text-align: right;
}

#sowing .wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(175px, 1fr));
  gap: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  text-align: left;
}

#sowing fieldset {
  border: 1px solid white;
}

#sowing legend {
  margin-left: 0.25rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

#sowing label, #sowing input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

#sowing label {
  margin-bottom: 0.25rem;
}

#sowing input {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

#sowing input[type="submit"] {
  display: inline;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
}
<form id="sowing">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Personal Information</legend>
      <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="firstname">
      <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="lastname">
      <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
      <input type="text" id="phone">
      <label for="email">E-Mail Address</label>
      <input type="text" id="email">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Mailing Address</legend>
      <label for="address">Street</label>
      <input type="text" id="address">
      <label for="city">City</label>
      <input type="text" id="city">
      <label for="state">State</label>
      <input type="text" id="state">
      <label for="zip">Zip Code</label>
      <input type="text" id="zip">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Credit Card Information</legend>
      <label for="ccnumber">Credit Card Number</label>
      <input type="text" id="ccnumber">
      <label for="expiration">Expiration Date</label>
      <input type="text" id="expiration">
      <label for="code">CVV</label>
      <input type="text" id="code">
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>




I'm, generally, opposed to extra markup.  Yes, it could be done that way.  It seems like that's the whole purpose to all the fancy features of CSS.

CSS does have many fancy features, but there is no feature (other than display: none) which allows you to exclude selected child elements from a grid element.
